# Generating plots and saving automatically in R

Tags: r, graph, plot

I created a list of title names and then modified a function i found  [here](http://www.r-bloggers.com/automatically-save-your-plots-to-a-folder/)

```
mcollist<-list(A,B,C,D)# where A,B,C and D are dataframes
namelist<-c("A","B","C","D")
for(i in 1:length(namelist)){

mypath <- file.path("C:","Users","myname","Desktop","PLOTS",paste("myplot_", namelist[i], ".jpeg", sep = ""))
  
  jpeg(file=mypath)
  mytitle = paste("my title is", namelist[i])
  multicolplot<-lapply(mcollist,function(data){pairs(data)})##this is a function that is creating multicollinearity plot for multiple 
  ##datasets stored as a list in 'mcollist'. 
  dev.off()
}
```

While I get the "number of plots" correct i.e. as many as the names in the list i created. The plots are all of the same dataset. I don't get any error so I'm not sure where the issue is here

The same plot that is being saved multiple times is the last one on which multicolplot function is running on.

## EDIT

The same function when applied to save Correlogram, won't work

```
    for(i in 1:length(data1)){
  
  
  mypath <- file.path("C:","Users","myname","Desktop","PLOTS",paste("myplot_", data1[i], ".jpeg", sep = ""))
  
  
  jpeg(file=mypath)
  mytitle = paste("Correlogram for", data1[i])
{
    a`cf(data1[,i],na.action=na.pass,main=paste(names(data1)[i]))`
  }
dev.off()
}
```

Data1 is a dataframe containing variables (as columns) on which I wish to run acf test as implemented by the following code:

```
acf(data1[,i],na.action=na.pass,main=paste(names(data1)[i]))
```

It is running acf on each column of data1 ignoring 'na' values and then pasting the names from data1 column names

I get the following error:

```
    Error in jpeg(file = mypath) : unable to start jpeg() device
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In jpeg(file = mypath) :
  unable to open file 'C:/Users/myname/Desktop/PLOTS/myplot_c(0.62, 1.13, 2.53, -0.97, 0.82, 3.9, 1.77, -0.85, 2.57, -1.1, 1.67, 1.38, 0.67, 2.73, 1.32, 0.84, 0.65, 0.96, -0.86, 0.97, 0.7, 1.05, -0.26, 0.04, 1.14, 1.46, 2.08, 1.2, 2.53, 2.49, 2.79, 2.16, 2.3, -1.29, 0.49, -1.28, 1.78, 1.26, -1.71, -3.89, 1.45, 2.2, 2.26, 1.13, 2.82, 0.83, -0.91, -0.02, 0.79, 0.71, 0, 1.37, 2.81).jpeg' for writing
2: In jpeg(file = mypath) : opening device failed
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: if i include print command just before dev.off(), nothing changes.

Comment: Wait, what is `mcollist`? If it is a list of data sets, did you mean to type `mcollist[[i]]`?

Comment: I just updated the code. mcollist is a list of dataframes on which lapply applies 'pairs' function to generate colinearity plot for all variables in a given dataframe contained in mcollist

Comment: Perhaps, you should replace `lapply` by just `pairs(mcollist[[i]])`, because you're already iterating through the list elements using `for` loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in your code is you're trying to use two loops (explicit one with `for` and implicit one with `lapply`) to iterate over the one list. So, you could simplify your code as in this example:

```
namelist<-c("A","B","C","D")

mcollist <- split(as.data.frame(matrix(runif(60),ncol=3)),rep(1:4,each=5))
names(mcollist) <- namelist

for(i in 1:length(namelist)){

  jpeg(file=sprintf('~/RR%s.jpeg',namelist[i]))
  mytitle = paste("my title is", namelist[i])
  pairs(mcollist[[i]],main=mytitle)
  dev.off()
}
```

It produces four files with different plots (only the first two are shown here):

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks this worked. Is there a way to enhance the quality of the plots. These jpegs are of pretty small size

Comment: `jpeg` command has `width` and `height` parameters (inspect `?jpeg`). However, I would consider using vector formats (pdf or eps) instead of jpeg. For example, to produce a pdf file basically you just need to replace the `jpeg` command by `pdf`` (or by `postscript` if you prefer eps).

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I could do pdf, but I needed individual images to include them in a word document. Thanks again

Comment: Marat, I hit a bump - i've updated the question to include the issue. Thanks for your help

Comment: I think you're using the entire column instead of the column name as a part of the output filename

Comment: This is the only thing that is diff " acf(data1[,i],na.action=na.pass,main=paste(names(data1)[i]))". If I run this segment alone, it works

Comment: No, I don't think so. You used `nameslist` as part of your filename in the original question, and now you're using `data1[i]`. I think you intended to do `names(data1[i])`

Comment: Thanks Marat- I wish I had an eye for such detail. That worked like a charm